# Avoiding repetition with underscore templates - backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Assume that I have a backbone model that has a bunch of boolean attributes:

```
Car = Backbone.Model.extend({});

car_one = new Car({
    a_c: true,
    mp3: true,
    gps: false,
    touchscreen: false,
    // etc...
})
```

I want to be able to render a list of these boolean attributes, and have an icon beside them, depending on true or false. If true, the icon will be a green tick, otherwise, display a red X icon.

Something in the lines of:

```
<ul>
<li><img src="tick.png">AC</li>
<li><img src="tick.png">MP3</li>
<li><img src="cross.png">Gps</li>
<li><img src="cross.png">Touch screen</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a better way to do this, instead of wrapping each `li` in an `if statement` in the template:

```
<% if (model.a_c === true) { %>
    // show tick...
<% } else { %>
   // show red cross..
<% } %>
```

I have approximately 12 boolean attributes that need to be rendered like this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access JavaScript functions from within your templates. So you could put something in `window` (i.e. the global scope):

```
window.underscore_helpers = {
    list_of_booleans: function(obj, bools) {
        // 'obj' is the object for the template, 'bools'
        // is an array of field names. Loop through 'bools'
        // and build your HTML...
        return the_html_li_elements;
    }
};
```

Then you'll want to take advantage of the [`variable` option to `_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> By default, **template** places the values from your data in the local scope via the `with` statement. However, you can specify a single variable name with the **variable** setting. This can significantly improve the speed at which a template is able to render.
>
> ```
>    _.template("<%= data.hasWith %>", {hasWith: 'no'}, {variable: 'data'});
>    => "no"
> ```

Then you can have something like this in your template:

```
<%= underscore_helpers.list_of_booleans(
    json,
    ['a_c', 'mp3', 'gps', 'touchscreen']
) %>
```

and use your template like this:

```
var html = _.template($('#t').html(), model.toJSON(), { variable: 'json' });
// or
var tmpl = _.template($('#t').html(), null, { variable: 'json' });
var html = tmpl(model.toJSON());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Yr4m5/

By using the `variable` option you'll have to say `<%= json.attribute %>` instead of `<%= attribute %>` but that's pretty minor.

You could use a similar approach to format the `<li>`s one by one and keep more of the HTML in the template.

Another option is to throw a `for` loop into your template, something like this:

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-underscore-template">
    <ul>
        <% var fields = ['a_c', 'mp3', 'gps', 'touchscreen' ] %>
        <% for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i) { %>
            <li class="<%= json[fields[i]] ? 'true' : 'false' %>"><%= fields[i] %></li>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/983ks/

You'll notice that this uses the `variable: 'json'` option as well, you need that so that you'll have something to use the `[]` on to grab a field by name when the name is in a variable.
This al

Comment: Good stuff, I'll definitely look into this